# .Net Setting Response Headers - Vary User-Agent

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to set the response header for my site - to tell google i have a mobile version on the same url.

So i'm trying to change

**Vary: Accept-Encoding**
to
**Vary: User-Agent**

My Hosting Provider has installed the following hotfix: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2877816?wa=wsignin1.0

I have created the code behind and deployed my dll:

```
public partial class set_headers : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Hello");
        Response.AppendHeader("Vary", "User-Agent"); 
    }
}
```

When I refresh the page and look at my headers it still says **Vary: Accept-Encoding**

How do i get this to change to: **Vary: User-Agent** :(

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding in web.config?

```html
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
    <remove name="Vary"></remove>
    <add name="Vary" value="User-Agent"></add>
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Hi @ace.spades I have tried adding this to the web.config and i get
Vary: User-Agent, Accept-Encoding
So it doesn't seem to have removed the original Vary...

Comment: But User-Agent is already in Vary header, you may have to set the UserAgent property to true and see if google now sees detects it.

Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders.UserAgent = true;

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.appendheader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> HTTP response headers that pertain to caching (Cache-Control, Expires, Last-Modified, Pragma, and Vary) might be deleted when the cache object model is used.

Comment: Hi @Widi, i've tried changing the cache response along with other things but can't get the value of Vary to change, any ideas?  Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["User-Agent"] = true;

Comment: this might help: `this.Response.Cache.SetVaryByCustom("User-Agent");` source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075901/cant-set-http-vary-header-in-asp-net-iis7-classic-mode

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old post but probably `Vary: Accept-Encoding` added by IIS to remove that you need to change the website settings in the IIS double click "HTTP Response Headers". In the next screen you add or remove headers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders/